# Testing setTimout with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to test a function that alerts users then closes after 3000. I am getting that the class still exists after the timeout function has been called. I am using bootstrap alerts, i wonder if i am testing correctly?

code to test:

```
  setTimeout(function () {
        let messages = document.getElementById("msg");
        let alert = new bootstrap.Alert(messages);
        alert.close();
    }, 3000);
```

script.test.js:

```
jest.useFakeTimers();
describe("Timer alerts and then closes after 3000", () => {

    beforeAll(() => {
        let fs = require("fs");
        let fileContents = fs.readFileSync("templates/base.html", "utf-8");
        document.open();
        document.write(fileContents);
        document.close();
    });

    test('closes the alert after 3 second via advanceTimersByTime', () => {
        const element = document.getElementById("msg");
        expect(element).not.toBeNull();


        require('../script');

        expect(document.querySelector('.alert')).toBeTruthy();
        jest.runAllTimers();
        jest.advanceTimersByTime(3000);
        expect(document.querySelector('.alert')).toBeNull();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see different details to check:

1- In the official documentation, says that need to add spy to global.setTimeout.
Add `jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');` after `jest.useFakeTimers();`.

2- Run the script, add `const script = require('../script'); script()` to run it

3- Check if setTimeout is called, add `expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` and `expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 1000);`

Official documentation: [jest timer-mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks)